# How to add a component visible on all pages and to send events from another component placed in column

Tags: visualforce-component, event, home-page-component

I'm extremely new to Salesforce development and recently have spend hours reading different docs. It's not an excuse, it's just that feel to correct me whenever I use incorrect terminology or make fals assumptions. My quesion is both technical - is it possible to implement at all? - and administrative (is it allowed to implement by guidelines, rules or whatever).

Here's what I bascially want to achieve - by clicking something in iframe in area [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iz9n.png) I want some other component install on all pages to react on that particular click.  As of this second component, a component that listens to events, I want it to be it placed either in footer just like the chatter component ([2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQEf3.png)) or as a sidebar ([3] and second screenshot - to remind you how it looks expanded).

[image]
[image]

So here's the summary of questions I'm asking:

1. How to add a custom footer component just like chatter one but with my own button.
2. Disregarding the fact whether footer component is implementable or not,  is it possible to add ad [3]-like sidebar. in Saleforce. This question actually boils down to whether we are allowed or not to insert arbitrary javascript on all SF pages.
3. How can I send events from within container [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iz9n.png) to the second container, wherever it will be placed.

To be more succint: I want to have a component placed in left column, a second component placed on all pages which also able to listen events from first component and to expand.